# Make border radius for photos in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a list of photos, different sizes and shapes, and I want to give them 10px border radius for everyone.

This is very helpful in every UI, when there are photos with different sizes.

How to perform this?

Comment: What does "for everyone" mean? Or do you mean "for every one"? If it's for a UI, would CSS `border-radius` be appropriate?

Comment: Different shaped photos? What? Are these photos or illustrations? I'm voting to close because right now its very unclear what you're asking. That's also why you've gotten a few answers that all produce different results.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers lead me to believe that I might have read between the lines a bit too much and therefore misunderstood the question. Just in case I didn't, here's my answer.

Before I explain the process, here's an example of what I think you want...

[image]

---

Things do get a bit complicated when you wish to export different size images with rounded corners.

I would perhaps do that with the help of Channels, Gaussian blur and Levels:

1. Open one of the files you wish to give rounded corners.
2. Start recording a new action.
3. Select all <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.
4. Top menu: `Select > Modify > Border...`. Width: `1` pixels.
5. In the `Channels panel`, click `Save selection as channel` icon (Looks the same as `Layer mask` icon in `Layers panel`).

   - If there's a chance that your image documents already contain channel `Alpha 1`, you might wanna click that icon while pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> and give it a distinct name. That way you don't accidentally take a selection from a wrong channel later on.
6. Click on the channel you just made, to select and reveal it.
7. Deselect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.
8. Top Menu: `Filter > Blur > Gaussian blur...`. Try to make the blur radius visually the size you want your rounded corner to be.
9. Levels are used to make that blurry rectangle into a crisp rounded rectangle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

   - This requires a bit more explanation:
   - You'll definitely want to zoom in for these steps so that you can hone in the  sharpness of the edge.
   - First move the black arrow as far to the right as it takes for the sides of the blurred rectangle to reach the edges of your document. ( ...or you can also leave some padding for like a `Drop shadow` or something. )
   - Then move the white arrow to the left so that all of the arrows are overlapping.
   - [Click here for a gif example of that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2cWh.gif)
10. Take a selection of the channel you made by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> clicking its thumbnail.
11. Turn RGB channel back on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>
12. Apply a layer mask based on the selection.

    - In the `Layers Panel` click the `Layer mask` icon while pressing
      <kbd>Alt</kbd>
13. Now you can save the document to the folder where you want to save the images once you run batch process. I used Save for web...
14. Then close the document <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>.
15. Stop recording the action.
16. Top menu: `File > Automate > Batch...`

    - Select the action you recorded.
    - Select source folder.
    - Destination: none. <sup>( Because your action already saves the files )</sup>

> On a mac replace every <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>.

Comment: It looks long, but tested it and I took me slightly less than 2 minutes to do all 16 steps. Then again, I didn't have to follow my own text and I knew exactly what I was doing...

Comment: In Sketch:
1. Drag square over image
2. Select border radius
3. Click 'mask'

Comment: @OliverDixon, it is just as simple in Photoshop, if that is the way you want to do it. The point of this answer is to be able to round corners of multiple images that may or may not be different size and you can run it on how every many images you want as an automated batch process. That's why it's somewhat complicated to setup. However, you only need to make the action once. After that it's only matter of processing images using the batch dialog (step 16). To further make my point, [here's a video of that last step](https://youtu.be/M6mp-HPInp8).

Answer (score 0):

You can double click the layer in Photoshop (assuming that its not a locked background layer), go to the "Stroke" option, select the colour and size you need. if you choose the "inside" position you wont need to resize the image to fit the extra stroke width.

Edit: I must add that you should probably exand on your question a bit, where are these images to be used, how large are the images etc.